# 301 redirection for Cakephp 2 using Router::Redirect

Tags: redirect, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, router, http-status-code-301

So I've been trying to get the Router::redirect to work for a project I'm working on.
I need to add a trailing slash for a couple of links.
The link atm is being displayed as "/page/contact" but what I need is "/page/contact/".

I've tried two ways to get it to 301 redirect from the routes.php file

1st Method

```
Router::connect('/page/contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'contact'));
Router::redirect('/page/contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'contact'), array(`status` => 301));
```

2nd Method

```
Router::connect('/page/contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'contact'));
Router::redirect('/page/contact', '/page/contact/', array(`status` => 301));
```

I've seen other methods where the .htaccess file is being changed but I've been specifically told by my boss to not use that method.

What can I do?

Edit

Okay so now I'm trying to redirect using the .htaccess file found in \app\webroot.htaccess

```
#Method 1
RedirectMatch 302 ^/page/contact http://mvwww/page/contact/
```

This method shows the correct URL but shows the error below in Fire Fox.

"***The page isn’t redirecting properly.
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.***"

Comment: Ask your boss what reason there might be to avoid the easiest and most efficient solution?

Comment: I think he's worried it'll create more problems than solutions. He may be right.. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right so I've found the solution to my problem.
Simple Redirect would not work so I used RedirectMatch as stated above but adding '$' to the end to show that the URL should be ending without a trailing slash.

`RedirectMatch 302 /page/contact$ http://mvwww/page/contact/`

The above line of code will redirect "mysite/page/contact" to "mysite/page/contact/"

Thank you for everyones help.
Have a great day.